# Installing npm canvas on elasticbeanstalk - npm install error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a node.js server running on EC2 via Elasticbeanstalk.
The problem I am having is during the rebuild of the canvas npm module.
The command 'canvas@1.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`' fails as follows:

```
> canvas@1.1.6 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink 'build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! canvas@1.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The problem appears to be that the `npm install canvas` command is not being run with appropriate privileges. If I manually ssh into the server and run 'sudo npm install canvas', everything works fine. This tells me that all the appropriate dependencies are installed fine (I followed these instructions: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Amazon-Linux-AMI-(EC2)). It's just the elasticbeanstalk deployment which is causing the grief.

I attempted to enable root access during deployment by adding commands to a .config file inside .ebextensions as follows:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles
    option_name: /public
    value: /public
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production

commands:
  01_enable_rootaccess:
    command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
  02_no-cert:
    command: sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.10-linux-x64/bin/npm config set ca ""
```

but it doesn't appear to make any difference.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get canvas to install nicely during eb deployment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have all the dependencies for canvas? In order for it to work for me, I had to install the following: `cairo`, `cairo-devel`, `libjpeg-devel`, `giflib-devel`, `libpng-devel` (should already be installed).

You can ensure all of these are installed by adding the following in one of your `.ebextensions`:

```
packages:
    yum:
        cairo: []
        cairo-devel: []
        libjpeg-devel: []
        giflib-devel: []
        libpng-devel: []
```

I think canvas might be trying to install things it doesn't have which it doesn't have permissions for.

Try that out and let me know how it works.

Comment: This should be placed in : /.ebextensions/node.config - correct ?